# How to add startup status indicator to custom services

Tags: linux, service, debian, init.d

Running my custom service at startup, how do I add a status message (e.g. ok|warn|error) in square brackets, like the ones associated with other services?

Comment: The way status messages are displayed is a highly distribution dependent matter. Including the GNU/Linux distribution you're using in the tags of your question would help a lot to produce an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to dig up the required information through [this archive](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2005/11/msg01309.html)

A quick example usage would be:

```
. /lib/lsb/init-functions
...
log_daemon_msg Foo "Starting script... "
...
log_progress_msg "Done"
log_end_msg 0
```

Further examples can be found in the included `init-functions` script and other scripts in  `/etc/init.d` dir.